# Stylesheet problems when running locally vs. on web

Tags: javascript, html, stylesheet, local

I am a newbie to HTML and I've been trying to teach myself by grabbing source code from major websites and playing around with it on my local machine.

Today I have been playing around with the Huffington Post, and I got everything to look pretty good on my local machine.

But when I put it online to share with a friend, the page looked much worse, as if the stylesheet had not been applied.

See the screenshots attached. Any suggestions?

EDIT: stylesheet code is directly below

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://s.huffpost.com/assets/css.php?v=1442936909&f=verticals%2Fhomepage.css%2Cfrontpage.css%2Cfonts%2Fopensans-condbold%2Fstylesheet.css%2Ctopnav_new%2Fall_pages.css%2Ctopnav_new%2Ftop_nav.css%2Ctopnav_new%2Fmodule.edition_nav.css%2Cbasic.css%2Cverticals%2Fcolor_scheme.css%2Cadd%2Ffront.css%2Cbuttons.css%2Cmost_popular.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
```

[image: Looking good on local machine.]

[image: Looking bad on web.]

Comment: show us how you included stylesheet

Comment: are the style sheets taking relative paths?

Comment: You should use the developer tools in your browser to see if there are any obvious errors (e.g. the stylesheet is not loading)

Comment: though the one of reason css is not loading is because they are not properly included.. so developer tools will help you to know error like

Comment: Thanks for the comments - I made an edit to include the stylesheet code.

Comment: At more than 1.5k rep you should know how to ask a better question than this.  Don't just ask a question where you dump everything in it and ask people to guess whats wrong.

Comment: @JK I understand - I tried to make it as little of a "dump everything in" as I could. Perhaps the screenshots were overkill. I have just the one line of code in my question. I have been pulling my hair out over this one and perhaps should have phrased it more generally.

Comment: @JeffGrimes You said you put that site online. Can you share the link too ?

Comment: @JK. come on .. rep has nothing to do with this

Comment: are you sure you have css.php ? as well as other css files shown in query string

Comment: I am feeling like i am human debugger and doing work of console..... can you just open developer tool and see damn things in console and network tab ... its just one press away  just  press F12  (ffs)

Comment: @NullPointer downloading the css.php did the trick! it is showing up online now. thanks for your help!